# Entity framework property computed from entries in another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have a movie renting application (DVD, Blueray or some other physical media) and after a user has returned the movie they can rate it. This is a simplified version of the tables:

```
Ratings
--------------------------------------------
| Id | UserId | MovieId | Rating (1 to 10) |
--------------------------------------------

Movies
------------------------------------------
| Id | Name | Computed rating (1 to 100) |
------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to configure Entity Framework to calculate a movie's rating using the entries in the Ratings table? Because having a Rating field in the Movies table would be a bit redundant and I was wondering whether Entity framework can handle it for me without me having to do it every time I load the Movies.

I know nHibernate can associate formulas with properties.

Comment: Code first? http://geekswithblogs.net/DavidPaquette/archive/2012/09/23/calculated-columns-in-entity-framework-code-first-migrations.aspx otherwise add a computed column to your table and map it with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`

Comment: Alternatively, add a `[NotMapped]` property to your entity class and do the calculation locally.

Comment: @spender I've read this article. "The question was, is there a way to specify a property in my C# class that is the result of some calculation involving 2 properties of the same class." That is not the question I'm asking though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing an aggregate value would be accomplished with an SQL trigger.

To create the trigger, you'll need to override the `Seed` method in an initializer (`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` seems to fit the bill in your case).

For example, given the following models -

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SumOfAllRatings { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
}

public class Rating
{
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

}
```

and DbContext -

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(m => m.SumOfAllRatings)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)
    }
}
```

This is the initializer that creates an appropriate trigger -

```
public class MyInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
{
  string _sql = "create trigger T_Ratings_Change " +
       "on dbo.Ratings after insert, update as " +
       "update Movies set SumOfAllRatings = " +
       "(select SUM(Rating) from Ratings where MovieId = inserted.MovieId) " +
       "from Movies inner join inserted ON Movies.Id = inserted.MovieId";


  protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
  {
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(_sql);
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this going to just update the Rating column in the Movies table? I was looking for a way to avoid having that column in that table and having the Movie rating calculated for me on the fly when I'm pulling the Movie from the database.

Comment: The alternative is to create a get-only property `Movie.SumOfAllRatings` - `get { return Ratings.Sum(r => r.Rating); }` and mark it `[NotMapped]` or `modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Ignore(m => m.SumOfAllRatings)`. But I understood your statement **handle it for me without me having to do it every time I load the Movies** to mean that you wanted a different solution.